# Confused about POST, GET, PUT, DELETE

Tags: http

Before now, In my mind, both GET and POST are used to fetch resources from server. The only difference is POST request has the payload that contains extra data but GET request has no. Today I read this:

```
GET: **fetch an existing resource**. The URL contains all the necessary information the server needs to locate and return the resource.
POST: **create a new resource**. POST requests usually carry a payload that specifies the data for the new resource.
PUT: **update an existing resource**. The payload may contain the updated data for the resource.
DELETE: **delete an existing resource**.
```

I can't understand why POST can *create a new resource*. And I have never seen PUT and DELETE.

Can anyone explain for me? Thanks.

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article (seriously, it has better explanations): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Comment: You ask to explain it and you already provide the explanation. Is there anything unclear about what you read?

Comment: Thanks but I mean I understand that POST also fetch an existing resource, like GET. Ex. when I submit a form (it is POST, ok), a page is requested and I don't see any resource created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all HTTP "verbs" defined in the HTTP specification. There are others. It's helpful to think of HTTP verbs as ways to operate on abstract "resources". While servers can interpret requests any way they choose, it is helpful to use standard verbs so that resources can be managed in a standardized fashion. In the past, get and post were often used to interact with resources in multiple ways. This could sometimes result in the unhappy result of a get request deleting a resource, for instance. By using HTTP verbs to interact with resources there are fewer surprises. You can read about REST for more on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: If the poster can't understand "GET: **fetch an existing resource**. The URL contains all the necessary information the server needs to locate and return the resource.", I doubt highly that "HTTP verbs are ways to operate on abstract resources" or "managed in a standardized fashion" is going to clarify anything for them.

Comment: Was just hoping to get at some of the ideas behind REST. I found this helpful when I was learning some of this. What vs why.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['x'] is like $_SESSION['x'] where the value is hidden but it exists. To pass it on to the next page, it needs to create a resource to pass to the next page. The major difference is POST is only usable one time. Auto-refreshing codes for php clears the value of POST.

PUT and DELETE are self-explanatory. PUT is another method in replacing a variable value while DELETE is used to clear.

Comment: You've repeated less information than what the question quoted, and you've cluttered it up with language specific markup which is not part of the tags or question itself. How is that helpful?

Answer (score 0):

All have given nice explanations and descriptions. GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, etc are all called "HTTP verbs".  You know HTTP is a protocol designed to create what we call web today. The web works on a client-server model, that is, there are two components to make it happen: a client part (web browser) and a server part (web server). The client requests a web page (a resource on the server) and the server sends it to the client (if found), and then forgets about it. All these interactions happen through the said HTTP protocol.

When the client requests something from the server, it does it by sending the server an HTTP request. In that request, you can find one of those HTTP verbs. It's pretty simple. POST, and GET methods are well-known, and all web browsers support them. Most think that these two methods are more or less the same, and actually it's correct to a much extended level. You can use either of the two to achieve your simple task. They tend to think GET sends the request information appended to the url (like, for example, www.abc.com?sth=some). When you send the same data with a POST, the data is not appended as above, but inserted in the body part of the request. However, using either you achieve the intended operation.

The problem arises with other verbs, PUT, DELETE,HEAD etc. Actually, you don't need them necessarily, just as you have not needed so far. They have been and are in the HTTP protocol specification, but not used extensively, and that's why you don't know much about them. At least the several dozens of books I have been reading about web development and networking had no much details about them except POST and GET.

As the original poster had mentioned, the specification tries to put them into perspective by saying GET is for such thing, POST is for another, and blah blah blah. All correct, and you just nod saying "ah ok". That's it. However, when you try to do something with those verbs, you don't find the required support from browsers and servers. So, it's pretty safe with POST and GET, and you can do almost everything with them. (actually HEAD verb can be used for some nice and useful things)

Sure, as the spec says "GET" is for getting a resource from the server, and POST is for sending some data to the server so that the server can process those data accordingly. Yet, you can make GET do what POST is supposed to do, and make POST do what GET is supposed to do. It's no longer "safe" what it says "safe" and vice versa.  They only have semantic or symbolic significance, but if all uphold the standards strictly they would have very interesting and important impact too.